HttpRequest to HttpRequestData in .NET 8 (SwaggerUi)
I am updating to .NET 8 and changed to HttpRequestData in this method (before change):
private static async Task<ContentResult> ConfigureSwaggerUI(HttpRequest req, string title, string endpoint)
{
        var swaggerUi = new SwaggerUI();

        var openApiInfo = CreateOpenApiInfo(title);
        var routePrefix = req.Host.ToString().Contains("localhost") ? "api" : "doc";
        req.Host = new HostString(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("UrlEnv") ?? "localhost:7071");

        var httpRequestObject = new HttpRequestObject(req);

        var assembly = typeof(SwaggerUI).Assembly;

        var result =
            await swaggerUi
                .AddMetadata(openApiInfo)
                .AddServer(httpRequestObject, routePrefix)
                .BuildAsync(assembly)
                .RenderAsync(endpoint)
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
        return CreateContentResult(result);
}

This was working fine.
With the change to HttpRequestData like this:
private static async Task<ContentResult> ConfigureSwaggerUI(HttpRequestData req, string title, string endpoint)
{
        var swaggerUi = new SwaggerUI();

        var openApiInfo = CreateOpenApiInfo(title);
        var routePrefix = req.Url.Host.Contains("localhost") ? "api" : "doc";
        req.Headers.Remove("Host");
        req.Headers.Add("Host", $"{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("UrlEnv") ?? "localhost:7071"}");

        var httpRequestObject = new HttpRequestObject(req);

        var assembly = typeof(SwaggerUI).Assembly;

        var result =
            await swaggerUi
                .AddMetadata(openApiInfo)
                .AddServer(httpRequestObject, routePrefix)
                .BuildAsync(assembly)
                .RenderAsync(endpoint)
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
        return CreateContentResult(result);
}

Now the result won't be correct. Something seems wrong now with how the req and req.Host are handled.
Any idea what I've done wrong?
